# Using a CASE WHEN statement and an IN (SELECT...FROM) subquery

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a temp table and build out different CASE WHEN logic for two different medications. In short I have two columns of interest for these CASE WHEN statements; `procedure_code` and `ndc_code`. There are only 3 procedure codes that I need, but there are about 20 different ndc codes. I created a `temp.ndcdrug1` temp table with these ndc codes for medication1 and `temp.ndcdrug2` for the ndc codes for medication2 instead of listing out each ndc code individually. My query looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp.flags AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.userid,
                    CASE WHEN (procedure_code = 'J7170' OR ndc_code in (select ndc_code from temp.ndcdrug1))  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Drug1,
                    CASE WHEN (procedure_code = 'J7205' OR procedure_code = 'C9136' OR ndc_code in (select ndc_code from temp.ndcdrug2)) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Drug2,
                    CASE WHEN (procedure_code = 'J7170' AND procedure_code = 'J7205') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Both
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE...
AND...
```

When I run this, it returns: **org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in a Filter.**
I could list these `ndc_code` values out individually, but there are a lot of them so wanted a more efficient way of going about this. Is there a way to use a sub select query like this when writing out CASE WHEN's?

Comment: Edit your question and qualify all your column names so people reading the question can make some sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

Query.

```
CREATE TABLE temp.flags AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.userid,
          CASE WHEN (
            procedure_code = 'J7170' OR 
            (select min('1') from temp.ndcdrug1 m where m.ndc_code = a.ndc_code) = '1'
          )  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Drug1,
          CASE WHEN (
            procedure_code = 'J7205' OR 
            procedure_code = 'C9136' OR 
            (select min('1') from temp.ndcdrug2 m where m.ndc_code = a.ndc_code) = '1'
          ) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Drug2,
          CASE WHEN (procedure_code = 'J7170' AND procedure_code = 'J7205') 
          THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Both
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE...
AND...
```